# Correct way to use useEffect to update Child Component after replacing state array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a parent component "Checkout", where I call my api for the events tickets and save the data to state. I have a simple function that takes the existing ticket information and adds one to the ticket the user selected.

**Checkout Component**

```
    const handleTicketAdd = (e) => {
    // create new ticket array
    const newTickets = tickets;
    // 
    newTickets[e.target.id].count++;
    console.log(newTickets);
    setTickets(newTickets);
    console.log(tickets);
  }
```

This function is passed as a prop to the child component "Tickets" and is called in a mapped row.

The function works fine and is updating the count state in the console, but the child component is not re-rendering and the values on screen are staying at the inital value.

I have been researching and have found that componentWillReceiveProps has been replaced with the useEffect hook. I have been trying to get it to work in my child component without sucesss:

**Tickets Component**

```
useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("Tickets Changed", props.tickets);
}, [props.tickets]);
```

The log doesn't fire when props.tickets changes, so I know that I am not handling this correctly. Can someone point me in the right direction.

**Update**

Based on the below feedback I have revised my code and it's almost complete. The problem is that it's adding a new field the array with the count value of the object instead of just updating the count field of the object.

```
setTickets(prevTickets => ([...prevTickets, prevTickets[e.target.id].count = prevTickets[e.target.id].count + 1])
  )
```

If I try something like poping the last value, I get even more new fields added to the array. How would I achieve removing the additional field that's being generated. The following is not working:

```
    setTickets(prevTickets => ([...prevTickets, prevTickets[e.target.id].count = prevTickets[e.target.id].count + 1], prevTickets.pop()),
  )


    setTickets(prevTickets => ([...prevTickets, prevTickets[e.target.id].count = prevTickets[e.target.id].count + 1], prevTickets.slice(-1)[0),
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so it looks like the way to edit your array's in state should be done with a map function or loop using the previous state. I was able to work it out based on Shubham's feedback.

```
// update count based on previous state 
  setTickets(prevTickets => (prevTickets.map((ticket, index) => {
    console.log(index, e.target.id);
    // if mapped object's id equals the arrays index, it's the value to edit
    if (e.target.id == index) {
      console.log(index);
      const count = ticket.count + 1;
      // return object with updated count values
      return { ...ticket, count }
    }
    return ticket;
  })
  ))
```

This gives me an edit of the object value that I want in my array without any additional fields or values.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be mutating the state while updating, instead you need to clone and update the state

```
const handleTicketAdd = (e) => {
    const id = e.target.id;
    setTickets(prevTickets => ([
         ...prevTickets.slice(0, id),
         {
             ...prevTickets[id],
             count: prevTickets[id].count + 1
          }
         ...prevTickets.slice(id + 1);
    ]));
  }
```

Comment: This is close, but it destroys the array and only leaves the ticket row of the selected id. I want to keep the other fields that were not clicked intact and only update the count on the ticket that was selected. Anyways, I think this gets me off to a good start and ill play around.